# How can i command jasper server to directly print without download report?

Tags: jasperserver

I'm using **jasper server** from .Net app using REST API, How can i order the server to print the report directly instead of sending it to me ??

Comment: Your question is not clear. I am assuming you want to download report in different format instead of HTML. Is it true ? then you just need to pass proper download format while calling rest api.

Comment: No, what I mean I want the server to print the report directly using the attached printer instead of making a print-preview.